# Why are Xcode 10.2.1 fonts and colors are different from the Xcode 9?

Tags: xcode

I downloaded Xcode 10.2.1 and suddenly font colors default changed. I want to use the previous colors in Xcode 9 where the comments are green.

```
enum CompassPoint {
    case north, south, east, west
    mutating func turnNorth() {
        self = .north
    }
}
var currentDirection = CompassPoint.west
let rememberedDirection = currentDirection
currentDirection.turnNorth()

print("The current direction is \(currentDirection)")
print("The remembered direction is \(rememberedDirection)")
// Prints "The current direction is north"
// Prints "The remembered direction is west"
```

[image: Xcode 10 preferences - fonts and colors]
[image: Xcode9]
[image: Xcode 10]

Comment: It seems like you're looking for the "Basic" theme, which is on the top of the list.

Comment: No, it was not basic. There was default, default light and default dark theme but now only default light and default dark theme. Comments color gray not green.